# Ajuda treinamento OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Em um processo de criação de uma haarcascade, realizei os procedimentos segundo os tutoriais da biblioteca OpenCV e cheguei no resultado de um vetor com o número de 70 imagens positivas denominado ***positivos.vec***. O vetor está  sendo gerado corretamente, pois executando o comando a seguir, as imagens do vetor são mostradas:

```
opencv_createsamples -vec positivos.vec -show -w 20 -h 20
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu problema é na parte do comando de treinamento, ao executar o seguinte comando:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec positivos.vec -bg negativos.dat -numPos 70 -numNeg 35 -numStages 10 -minHitRate 0.8 -w 20 -h 20
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo negativos.dat está como na seguinte maneira:

`negativos/img1.jpg`

`negativos/img2.jpg`

`negativos/img3.jpg`

`negativos/img4.jpg`

`...`

`negativos/img1000.jpg`

Qual seria o problema com o comando de treinamento? Poucas imagens? Algo não adicionado corretamente? Como proceder?

Obs: estou utilizando o Windows 10 64bits.

Comment: Que tal mostrar a msg de erro original ao invés de imagens? Vc não acreditaria como fica pessimo de ver em alguns sistemas.

Comment: É que a mensagem de erro aparece direto no Prompt, eu executo o comando por lá e acaba dando erro junto com o aviso que o programa parou de funcionar. O erro principal que aparece no prompt é:

**OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.**

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o dobro de imagens negativas referente as imagens positivas exemplo 40 positivas para 80 negativas nao coloque menos do que o dobro das positivas nas negativas. Isso deve resolver esse erro.

Outra dica em featureType configure para LBP e nao HAAR é um otima combinacao essa para treinar imagens. Esse parâmetro indicam o tipo de algoritimo a ser processado LBP e o HAAR mais avançado.

Espero ter ajudado!